# tkinter debugging with Spyder

Tags: python, debugging, tkinter, spyder

I am using tkinter to build a GUI app with anaconda python and spyder on OSX. I can't get a prompt in the ipython console while my tkinter window is open.  I can set a breakpoint and get into the debugger, but after that Spyder will shortly freeze or crash.

Here is sample code that fails:

```
from tkinter import *

def toggle():
    i = 1
    b = 2
    print(i, b)
    pass

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root, width=100, height=100)
button = Button(frame,text="Press", command=toggle).grid(column=1, row=1)
frame.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I run the debugger and set a breakpoint in the toggle() function.  At the ipdb> prompt I can get the state of frame but nothing for button as below:

```
ipdb> frame
<tkinter.Frame object .4709317264>

ipdb> button
```

I click on the button in the tkinter window and back to the ipdb> prompt and soon spyder crashes.

Question 1:  Can this be fixed?
Question 2:  Is there a way to get a Spyder ipython console and variable explorer pane to function when a tkinter window open?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing frame.pack() to frame.grid()
in this gui you don't really need to use grid for geometry, though. So might just want to change Button().grid() to Button().pack().